# How does android figure out the MIME type of a URI for an implicit Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, mime-types, android-contentprovider

I'm currently learning to develop Android apps and have a fairly basic question:

Suppose I want to send out an implicit Intent to open up data specified by a URI link, e.g. "content://com.mynewauthority:8100/table1". And suppose I have created a custom Content Provider that maintains an SQLite table at "content://com.mynewauthority:8100/table1".

Now since I haven't specified the MIME type for my table, but only the URI to it, Android must be able to figure it out somehow. But since it is a custom-made table, I decide on the MIME type myself, so it could be "monkey/bananas" for all I know. I can't seem to find anywhere in the Content Provider implementation that specifies which MIME type goes with which URIs except the getType(URI uri) function which doesn't seem to be used by the Android system for Intent resolution.

So my question is: How does Android figure out the MIME types associated with URIs for custom-made content providers during resolution of implicit Intents?

Hope this question is clear enough!

Comment: "which doesn't seem to be used by the Android system for Intent resolution" -- and your proof of this is, what, exactly?

Comment: Ah sorry, my bad! I didn't test my app the right way. Now I managed to make the app break by changing getType() function. So basically the getType(URI uri) function is used by the Android system for intent resolution? That means the Android system can look up the content provider associated with the URI and use the getType() function to retrieve the MIME type.

Comment: No, it only needs to call `getType()` on the right `ContentProvider`, as determined by the authority (`com.mynewauthority`). BTW, you don't use port numbers with `ContentProvider`.

Comment: Okay, that's great. Thanks so much for your prompt help!

Answer (score 3):

If the `Intent` has a MIME type in it (see XGouchet's answer), then that is used.

If the `Intent` does not have a MIME type in it, Android will attempt to determine a MIME type:

- For a `ContentProvider`, as in your case, it calls `getType()` on the specific provider for that `Uri`, based on the authority
- For an `http://` `Uri`, it issues an HTTP `HEAD` request
- For most other stuff, it fails (e.g., a `file://` `Uri`)

Answer (score 0):

If you create your intent object yourself, you can force the mime type attached to it by using :

```
fileType = "monkey/bananas";
intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, fileType);
```

FYI, android usually detects the mime types from the file extension, using the [MimeTypeMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap.html), which I find rather incomplete. You can print the known file extensions and associated mime types from the [MimeTypeMap class source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap.java?av=f#MimeTypeMap.getSingleton%28%29)

Comment: `MimeTypeMap` may be used by `WebView`, but I have not seen any evidence it is used by much else.